# Suddenly not able to call Mojo.Controller.stageController.pushScene() from app-assistant

Tags: javascript, webos, mojo

```
Here is how the code is.
function AppAssistant() {
    this.dbObj = new DatabaseAssistant();
    this.schemaObj = new SchemaAssistant();
    this.result = {};
}

AppAssistant.prototype.setup = function() {
}

AppAssistant.prototype.handleLaunch = function(launchParams) {
    if (gConfigDatabase.engine == "sqllite") {

    } else {

    }
}

AppAssistant.prototype.processResult = function() {    
}

AppAssistant.prototype.execMigrations = function(version) {    
}

// Database error handler
// If the db does not exists, it will generate set of tables
AppAssistant.prototype.errorHandler = function() {
    Mojo.Log.info("In app asst error handler.");
    if (gConfigDatabase.engine == "sqllite") {

        try {
// execute some queries to create tables and insert some values in the HTML Opendatabase.

            // Show disclaimer Page
            Mojo.Controller.stageController.pushScene('disclaimer');
        } catch (e) {
            Mojo.Log.error("In AppAssistant errorHandler : ", e);
        }
    } else {
        Mojo.Log.info("db8 part of app asst error handler");

        try {
    // execute operations to create kinds for db8 analogous to tables 
            Mojo.Controller.stageController.pushScene("disclaimer");
        } catch (e) {
            Mojo.Log.info("Error in db8 appAsst error handler", e);
        }
    }
}

AppAssistant.prototype.handleCommand = function(event) {
}
```

All this was done to support both sqllite and db8 for an webOS app. The problem i am facing is that when i configure a variable (**gConfigDatabase**) as **sqllite** then the Mojo.Controller.stageController.pushScene` method which is there in the **errorHandler** function works. but when i change it so that **db8** engine is used, then i get an error saying undefined method **pushScene**. Any clues or hints on debugging or solving this ?

Comment: The last thing I expected not to work while working on this migration was this line. :@